# How many pixels' margin to the right should my 5"-wide image be on a 300dpi KDP paperback to be centered?

Tags: formatting, artwork, kindle, amazon, book-cover

**How many pixels' margin to the right should a 5"-wide image be on a 300dpi cover, for a 6"x9" KDP paperback, to have the front cover centered on Amazon.com and print books?**

I calculated based on a 6"-wide front cover plus .125" for bleed on the left, and .375" for bleed on the right.

However, when I tried to use that, paperback covers were showing up as significantly off-center, so I tried to recalculate based on the first cover that I attempted to center and saw off-center.

How many pixels to the right should I be placing the 5" wide image (which is part of, but not all of, the intended paperback cover)?

Answer (score 1):

Amazon provides cover templates here: https://kdp.amazon.com/en_US/cover-templates